# Location of Wiki Variable Settings e.g for [[Image:imageFile]] Substitution

Tags: image, parameters, http, wiki

Having a nightmare converting site from old http:// to https:// protocol.

I can't find settings that change the root of wiki article links to https:// nor that do the same for images.

The file under Edit File Upload Preferences under URL and server path are both correct yet any [Image:imageFile]] is still being replaced using http://.

The site_url variable has been changed (and the blog content reflects this) but the wiki seems to be behaving differently.

Comment: From memory Wiki uploads use the file upload URL/path settings, are they set correctly?

Comment: Yes - in Admin | General Configuration, the site_url setting in the index.php and File Upload Preferences - all use https:// whereas they get parsed as http://